# Is it a good practice to use switch case in useEffect Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-functional-component

I am handling some functionality in some functions. Basically I am handling some states in multiple functions. Those functions need to be called when particular state updates. Now there are a lot of states to be updated. So I tried this approach, I created a function for specific case and then set their state according to that value but it is all in a useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (notificationAction && actualCase) {
        switch (actualCase) {
            case firstCase:
                handleStatesBasedOnFirstCase();
                break;
            case firstCase:
                handleStatesBasedOnSecondCase();
                break;
        }
    }
}, [actualCase, notificationAction])
```

And that function is also a callback.

```
const handleStatesBasedOnFirstCase = useCallback(() => {
    if (someState !== props.someState) {
        // Setting some states here
    }
}, [somestates...])
```

Is it a good practice? Or shall I just give conditions while initialising the state.

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(props.someState || props.someOtherValue);
```

I think setting props in useState is not a good practise. That is the reason why I am trying to maintain multiple functions to set a proper state as per the proper cases and conditions. Please help me.

Comment: Sounds like a great place to use a reducer to me.

Comment: Here's some examples; personally I find the docs currently not overly helpful for explaining reducers. https://kentcdodds.com/blog/should-i-usestate-or-usereducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Nikki9696 answer in the comments, using reducer will do the job.